# Where is praying 2 and 2 sunnah prayers before Zuhr comes from?

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, sunnah

I do know its been a sound Islamic practice to pray 2 and 2 sunnah prayers before Zuhr. I just wondering if I prayed ahead to catch with a group prayer without sunnah, will that be haram or its recommanded to make up the 2 and 2 sunnah prayers afterward when the Zuhr is completed?

> Again the question is :
>
> 1.What is the source for the 2 and 2 sunnah prayers before Zuhr?
>
> 2.Will it be haram to not to pray the 2 and 2 sunnah prayers before Zuhr because catching up the Zuhr group prayer?

Please provide Quranic / Hadith reference with your answer, jazaklahir!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your answer...

**To Question 1.**

There are many optional (nawafil) prayers. 12 units (raka'ah) are ascribed or related to 4 (out of the 5) compulsory prayers - Fajr/Subh, Zuhr, Magrib and Isha.

The hadeeth for this is:

> “A house will be built in paradise for every Muslim who offers twelve
>   Rak’ah of optional salah other than the obligatory salah in day and
>   night, to seek pleasure of Allah.”

Source: Muslim

So if someone knows that value of a palace in paradise, I don't think they'll take this lightly.

**To Question 2.**

Is it haraam or sinful to miss the optional prayers? No. How can it be? That's why they're called optional prayers. But it is certainly a sin to miss any of the compulsory prayers (5 times a day).

However, as mentioned before, if someone does it (i.e., the optional prayers), they get the rewards for it. But if it's not done, there's no sin.

And Allaah knows best.