# Can i pray a Sunnah prayer before the Azan?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Can i pray a Sunnah prayer before the Azan is announced ? For example, i want to pray the Wudhu Sunnah Salaat and the Azan for the Asr prayer hasnt still been announced (but will be announced soon ).In this circumstance am i allowed to pray the sunnah wudhu salaat ?

Will the answer be applicable to all types of salaat ?

Please Clarify.

Comment: Check this out: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/34952

Comment: What is the sunnah wudhu salat or what do you mean by it? A fard prayer has related sunnah prayers some must be performed prior to fard others afterwards so the answer will certainly not be applicable to all types of salat.